# Mocha: ReferenceError: window is not defined when testing react with shallow rendering?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, mocha.js

I'm new to the unit testing world with React, and was following along with an egghead video on the subject. In trying out shallow rendering, tests only work with some of my components.

A few of my components, however, contain charts made using react-chartist and the chartist library. When attempting to run tests on those components, I get this error:

```
> kindred-web-healthreader@0.0.1 test /Users/HilaryMBP/Kindred/kindred-web-healthreader
> mocha './src/**/*.spec.js' --compilers js:babel/register

/Users/HilaryMBP/Kindred/kindred-web-healthreader/node_modules/chartist/dist/chartist.js:958
}(window, document, Chartist));
  ^

ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at /Users/HilaryMBP/Kindred/kindred-web-healthreader/node_modules/chartist/dist/chartist.js:958:3
    at Chartist.version (/Users/HilaryMBP/Kindred/kindred-web-healthreader/node_modules/chartist/dist/chartist.js:11:22)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/HilaryMBP/Kindred/kindred-web-healthreader/node_modules/chartist/dist/chartist.js:15:2)
    at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/HilaryMBP/Kindred/kindred-web-healthreader/node_modules/babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/api/register/node.js:214:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:313:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/HilaryMBP/Kindred/kindred-web-healthreader/src/js/utils/ChartistUtils.js:13:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
    at normalLoader (/Users/HilaryMBP/Kindred/kindred-web-healthreader/node_modules/babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/api/register/node.js:199:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/HilaryMBP/Kindred/kindred-web-healthreader/node_modules/babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/api/register/node.js:216:7)
   at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:313:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at /Users/HilaryMBP/Kindred/kindred-web-healthreader/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:219:27
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Mocha.loadFiles (/Users/HilaryMBP/Kindred/kindred-web-healthreader/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:216:14)
    at Mocha.run (/Users/HilaryMBP/Kindred/kindred-web-healthreader/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:468:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/HilaryMBP/Kindred/kindred-web-healthreader/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:403:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:313:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:457:10)
    at startup (node.js:138:18)
    at node.js:974:3
```

This only happens with components whose children import Chartist or react-chartist.

Here's my test file that's not working, for reference:

```
import React from 'react';
import TestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils';
import expect from 'expect';
import expectJSX from 'expect-jsx';
import Pain from '../components/Pain/Pain.jsx';

expect.extend(expectJSX);

describe('Pain', () => {

    it('should render', () => {
        const renderer = TestUtils.createRenderer();
        renderer.render(<Pain />);
        const actual = renderer.getRenderOutput();
        const expected = '';
        expect(actual).toIncludeJSX(expected);
    });
});
```

What could be happening here?

Comment: Shallow rendering is a technique for testing components without the need for a DOM. If any of your components need access to dom objects like `window` you'll need something like jsdom. Give this a try https://github.com/rstacruz/mocha-jsdom

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think this is close, but there's still something missing. I tried using mocha-jsdom and called jsdom() inside the describe block, but I still got the same error. It's like the problem is happening with the importing of the component and the libraries that it uses, but I don't know how to make window available at that point...

Comment: get anywhere with this?